# Is it fair to edit a question or answer to undo a locked vote on it?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, locked-votes

I want to undo my locked vote on a question or answer. The only way I can see is to edit the question or answer. The edit can be a superfluous edit or a good edit. So is it fair to edit the question or answer to undo or remove a locked vote on it?

Comment: tl;dr: stop worrying about it. Edit honestly and vote honestly; there's always some opportunity for both.

Answer (score -2):

No.

["Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged."  And specific guidelines for when you should edit.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)

Not to mention that skirting rules like the vote lock is obviously somethin that is not encouraged.